# Creative Commons: "Public Domain Mark" icon

Tags: symbols, licensing

Is there a symbol available in Latex indicating "Public Domain Mark"? See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Domain_Mark) or [creative commons](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/) so what I'm looking for is this symbol:

[image]

So far I used the [ccicons package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ccicons?lang=de) but it seams that this symbol is not part of it.

Comment: save that image as ccmark.png and use `\includegraphics{ccmark.png}`

Comment: It also exists as an SVG file [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cc-public_domain_mark_white.svg). You can convert that to PDF and use it.

Comment: I suggest filing a bug/enhancement request against the [`ccicons` GitHub repository](https://github.com/ummels/ccicons). BTW, the package author also has a [user account on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4087/michael-ummels).

Answer (score 2):

The public domain icon was added in version 1.6 of the `ccicons` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{ccicons}

\begin{document}
\ccPublicDomain
\end{document}
```

[image]